# unhandled exception when using Navigation.PushAsync

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

Some of the pages in my application -like the `FillForm` page- requires registration at first. to ensure that the user can't open those pages without being registered I did the following

- Made a form for registration in a page with class name `Registration`
- Created a new class called `ContentPageRequiresRegistration`

---

```
public class ContentPageRequiresRegistration : ContentPage
{

    private static enumUserType userType;

    public ContentPageRequiresRegistration():base()
    {
        if(userType==enumUserType.unRegistered)
            Task.Run(() => this.LoadRegitrationPage()).Wait();

    }

    private async void LoadRegitrationPage()
    {
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new Registration(false));
    }
}
```

- Extended pages that requires registration from `ContentPageRequiresRegistration`

`public partial class FillForm:ContentPageRequiresRegistration { ... }`

And in `App.cs` file

```
public App(){
MainPage = new NavigationPage(new FillForm(1));
}
```

---

`FillForm` xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPageRequiresRegistration xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="HuraApp.Pages.FillForm"
             Title="Fill forms">
</ContentPageRequiresRegistration>
```

But when I run the application it gives me an `unhandled exception`, and after some debugging it seems to be caused by the navigation statement

`await Navigation.PushAsync(new Registration(false));`

Why is this problem happening, and how can I solve it?

Comment: What's the actual exception?

Comment: It doesn't give me any other details when I try to run the applications; it just gives me a message that says `An unhandled exception occured.`

Comment: use a try catch, or setup your debugger to catch unhandled exceptions

Comment: `Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParseException: Position 6:6. Property Content is null or is not IEnumerable\n  at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.ApplyPropertiesVisitor.Visit`

Comment: Looks it fails inside Registration constructor. You should also change private async Task LoadRegitrationPage() to return Task. Then you will be able to catch exceptions. Is your Registration class a Page?

Comment: That sounds like a page with malformed XAML.

Comment: @YuriS Yes, the `Registration` class a Page. The code fails in the `LoadRegitrationPage` method.

Comment: @Jason I've updated my questions with the xaml of `FillForm` page; It's just empty.

Comment: The message is pretty explicit - "Content is null..." - I would try adding a Content node

Comment: @Jason I tried that already, but gives the same error.

Comment: are you sure the problem isn't on Registration?

Comment: @Jason Yes I am; The problem appeared only when I started using `ContentPageRequiresRegistration` class.

Comment: can you share the whole project code? It shouldn't be big

Comment: or at least provide Registration page xml and code behind. I don't see any content in ContentPageRequiresRegistration page. Do you add it in code behind? According to an error you get you don't.

Comment: Please upload your full project on github (or anywhere else where we are able to access the full source code). I just created a project out of the info you provided and it worked fine. So please share your full code.